# Showing a link to a folder on website hosted on raspberry pi

Tags: html, linux, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to host a website on a Raspberry pi4. I'm having some problems displaying the folder.
The code below is what I have so far, but, the following error message appears when I press the link: The requested URL was not found on this server.

````
<title> Folder </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Folder</h1>
<a href ="\home\pi\Documents" > Click to open folder </a>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious problems here:

Path separators in UNIX/UNIX-like operating systems (including Linux) and in URLs are `/`, not `\`.

URLs need to be provided by an HTTP server (such as Apache HTTPD, Nginx, or Lighttpd). In a traditional configuration (designed to just serve up static files) the root of the website will map on to a specific directory on the file system, and not the root of the file system (which would expose all sorts of private files).

The path you need to ask for needs to treat `/` as the server's root directory and not the file system's root directory.

Comment: thanks for the paths separators, I fixed that but is still not working. Can you explain me the HTTP part? I'm just hosting a website on a private VPN